# Aligning text always in the center of div next to image?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/joel081112/6yud4bvo/3/

I have this fiddle which shows my current situation. I cant get my text to always be aligned in the middle of the div next to the image. At the minute the text stays level with the top of the div.

I have tried `vertical-aligned` and `top: 50%` but I must be missing something easy

```
.homeInfo2 {
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}


.homeIm1 {
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item > div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```
<article class="item">
    <div class="homeInfo2">
      some text 1
    </div>
    <div class="homeIm2">
      <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/11/13fad36a93db836e4eaa1906b8f16433-full.jpg">

    </div>
  </article>
```

That code is the crux of what I'm using

Comment: Here are some good instructions: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `.item` element is a flexbox set `align-items: center` on the item:

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.homeIm1 {
  height: auto;
}

.homeInfo2 {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .item,
  .item:nth-child(odd) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item>div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <article class="item">
    <div class="homeInfo2">
      some text 1
    </div>
    <div class="homeIm2">
      <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/11/13fad36a93db836e4eaa1906b8f16433-full.jpg">

    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>

  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text 2
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image 2
    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="homeInfo2">
      some 1 text blah
    </div>
    <div class="homeIm2">
      <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/11/13fad36a93db836e4eaa1906b8f16433-full.jpg">

    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if you have a look at my jsfiddle I have it in a flex box

Comment: But you haven't set `align-items: center;` on the `.item`.

Comment: Aww thats fab! Thank you! Didnt realise the slight difference you had

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex.
You have to create a div next to the image and then justify-content-center and align-items-center. For more information use google :) Especially css-tricks would be helpful! [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you! Align-items... what a saviour

Answer (score 1):

Just add `align-items: center;` in your item class.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.item>div {
  width: 50%;
}




.homeIm1 {
    height: auto;
    float: right;
}

.homeInfo2 {
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {

  .item,
  .item:nth-child(odd) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .item>div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <article class="item">
    <div class="homeInfo2">
      some text 1
    </div>
    <div class="homeIm2">
      <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/11/13fad36a93db836e4eaa1906b8f16433-full.jpg">

    </div>
  </article>
   <hr>

  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
  <hr>
    <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text 2
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image 2
    </div>
  </article>
 <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="homeInfo2">
      some 1 text blah 
    </div>
    <div class="homeIm2">
      <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/11/13fad36a93db836e4eaa1906b8f16433-full.jpg">

    </div>
  </article>
 <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
 <hr>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="text">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      some image
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That align-items is great!